# css vertical tabs in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, ajaxcontroltoolkit, menubar

I want a vertical tab menu using css that will appear like ajax control toolkit tab container.Please see the [second example in the link](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/Tabs/Tabs.aspx).
I need to achieve this with css without having to use ajax control toolkit.

Comment: I don't think is about CSS here, but more about of how do you maintain the states of the panels between postbacks.

Comment: Or can I do it with asp.net menu control ??

Answer (score 0):

You can look at the CSS it produces and make a jQuery script to control the states, like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {       
    var tabs = $('div.tabs > div');
    tabs.hide().filter(':first').show();

    $('ul.tab_nav li a').click(function() {
        tabs.hide();
        tabs.filter(this.hash).show();
        $('ul.tab_nav li a').parent().removeClass('selected');
        $(this).parent().addClass('selected');
        return false;
    }).filter(':first').click();
}
```

With some HTML like:

```
<ul class="tab_nav">
    <li><a href="#tab-1">Tab 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab-2">Tab 2</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tabs">
    <div id="tab-1">
        Tab 1
    </div>
    <div id="tab-2">
        Tab 2
    </div>
</div>
```